# Webpack 4 - Unable to load CSS in SCSS file via relative paths

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I'm working on a legacy project that is required to run on node 8.x. As such, it can only run on Webpack 4 or older. I've been fairly successful in converting the project, but I've encountered an issue while trying to get the webpack dev server and hot reloading working.

I was previously using webpack's `resolve` aliases to direct the bundler where to access the files, and while that works great for producing the final bundle, when leveraging the dev server, it appears that the aliases are not used. In an effort to make hot reloading work, I've started moving the SCSS files away from the aliases and onto relative paths.

Thus far, I've been unable to get any of the various loaders to respect the relative paths used within the SCSS and CSS files.

So far, I've tried: `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, `resolve-url-loader`, `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader`, `mini-css-extract-plugin`, and I'm sure a dozen more.

My application file structure is the following:

```
webapp
├── dist/
|   ├── public/
|   ├── server.js
├── src/
|   ├── client/
|   |   ├── app/ (lots of SCSS in here, all resolves fine)
|   |   ├── content/
|   |   |   ├── css/
|   |   |   |   ├── base.scss
|   |   |   |   └── alert.css (can't resolve using ./alert.css or any variation)
|   |   |   └── lib/ (some CSS here)
|   |   ├── style/
|   |   |   └── app.scss
|   |   ├── index.html
|   |   └── index.js
|   └── server/
├── webpack.dev.config.js 
└── webpack.server.config.js
```

My webpack configuration looks something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000', './src/client/index.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all my other loaders here
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        // test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // this is what I use when I'm using aliases
        use: [
          'style-loader', // I've tried with and without this
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client'),
      'node_modules'
    ],
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname),
      Css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'content', 'css'),
      Img: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'content', 'img'),
      Lib: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'content', 'lib'),
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'client', 'app', 'components')
    },
    extensions: ['.html', '.js', '.css', '.scss', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif']
  },
};
```

The error I receive when running webpack is:

```
ERROR in ./src/client/style/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-3!./src/client/style/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve './alert.css' in 'C:\git\my-app\webapp\src\client\style'
    at doResolve (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:209:21)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn44 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at resolver.getHook.tapAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\RootPlugin.js:37:38)
    at _next43 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:8:1)
    at _fn43 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:1)
    at hook.callAsync (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:285:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (C:\git\my-app\webapp\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
 @ ./src/client/style/app.scss 2:26-200 53:4-74:5 56:18-192
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000 ./src/client/index.js
```

My `base.scss` file has some imports that look like so:

```
// CSS
@import "./alert.css";

// also tried
@import "Css/alert.css"; // <- This works when bundling, but fails when using the dev server and hot-reload. It has the same error as above.

@import "/src/client/content/css/alert.css"; // same error as above, but with src/client/content/... as the listed directory
```

I understand that the `css-loader` tries to use the output (or rather the importing file location) for its relative path, but for the sake of not editing hundreds of legacy files, how can I get relative imports working?

Comment: Can you retry with the `.css` extensions removed from your import statements and confirm that you get the same error?